# How can I export images stored on a amazon s3 server to my local rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm hosting a rails app on heroku and store the images via carrierwave on an amazon s3 server.

Now I want to make some changes and would like to use real data for a better development environment.

The app hosted on heroku can be downloaded by "heroku fork", but how can I get the images in my local (postgresql) database matching the carrierwave urls?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but, it sounds weired to me the idea of importing all production images to development evironment to have a "better" development environment?

Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the images are stored in S3 you should be able to just login to the Amazon Web Services dashboard, browse to the bucket(s) in question, and download your image files to your dev machine.

Then change the location being referenced by your application to the local for the images and you should achieve the result you want.

You could accomplish this by adding a hosts entry to point all DNS requests to your bucket to your local machine instead.

E.g. given an object url like `mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image1.jpg`, add a hosts entry on your dev machine to point mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com to localhost and have apache serve the image files from there.